# Преобразовать int в enum

Tags: c#, преобразование, enum

Как можно преобразовать `int` в `enum` в C#-e?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Из `int`:

```
CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)number;
```

**Можно еще и:**

```
CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CustomEnum), number);
```

### Из `string`:

```
CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomEnum), str);
```

Answer (score 6):

Прежде чем преобразовывать число в перечисление необходимо проверить, принадлежит ли число перечислению, чтобы не выйти за пределы enum и не получить неожиданного поведения кода из-за непредвиденного значения:

```
int number = 1;
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CustomEnum), number)) 
{ 
    CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)number; // преобразование 
    // или CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CustomEnum), number);
}
```

Документация на MSDN:

1. [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx)
2. [enum (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)
3. [Enumeration Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)
4. [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

Из примера документации на MSDN:

```
using System;

[Flags] enum Colors { None=0, Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 };

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] colorStrings = { "0", "2", "8", "blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red, Green" };
      foreach (string colorString in colorStrings)
      {
         Colors colorValue;
         if (Enum.TryParse(colorString, out colorValue))        
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorValue) | colorValue.ToString().Contains(","))  
               Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", colorString, colorValue.ToString());
            else
               Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
         else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a member of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
      }
   }
}

//   The example displays the following output:
//       Converted '0' to None.
//       Converted '2' to Green.
//       8 is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.
//       blue is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
//       Converted 'Blue' to Blue.
//       Yellow is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
//       Converted 'Red, Green' to Red, Green.
```

В примере имеет место проверка `Enum.IsDefined`. Обезопасить свой код от возможных ошибок - не является признаком плохого тона программирования, я так думаю.

Comment: В подавляющем большинстве живых ситуаций - это абсолютно лишнее и попахивает "индусизмом". Практически единственное исключение - пользовательский ввод.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, до определенного момента я тоже считал некоторые проверки излишними. Но когда в коде появляются потенциальные ошибки - это не есть хорошо. Конечно, себя не обезопасить от всех ошибок, но некоторые проверки делать стоит.

Comment: Чушь. Исключения при преобразовании из числа не вылетают: https://ideone.com/1EDWKg

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен. Но вместо ожидаемого слова у Вас будет выведена цифра. Не чушь, а небольшая оговорка. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, по поводу исключения - может вылететь исключение, к примеру, если будет идти преобразование из строки. Тогда получим исключение типа `Запрошенное значение "строка" не найдено`. Я рассмотрел немного более широкий спектр применения преобразования в перечисление, не думаю, что это будет лишним.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, повторюсь, если на входе у вас не пользовательский ввод, в любой его форме - такие проверки в коде бессмысленны. Ибо всё что остаётся - это получение обьекта исходного типа из промежуточного типа, в который он по какой-либо причине был преобразован. Нет смысла проверять в коде то, что абсолютно никогда не сможет произойти. А вот если строите библиотеку, потребитель которой неизвестен - применяйте лучше контракты, а не такие вот "местечковые" проверки.