# Создание из строки => Enum c#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как можно из строки(полученой из файла) создать Enum? Я могу сам разделить строку на подстроки, но как из подстрок сделать Enum?

Так же буду рад примеру.

**UPD**

Уточню. У меня имеется строка (это только пример)"Float,Array,Bool,Double,Int".
мне нужно прочитать строку из файла, разделить ее на части ориентируясь на запятую.
И на основе этой строки сделать Enum.

Причем состав строки заранее не известен, и количество запятых тоже.

Comment: Энумератор? Это интерфейс) Enum - перечисление. Так что вам надо?)

Comment: Enum, спасибо что обьяснили с энемератором.. я не знал что энумератор это что то вроде итератора)

Comment: Что значит сделать Enum? В рантайме работающий? Так нельзя. Опишите кейс, как вы собиратетесь использовать этот Enum после его создания.

Comment: для чего и как вы собираетесь `Enum` использовать? Допустимые значения `Enum`-типа должны быть известны заранее, чтобы можно было сделать преобразование. Если допустимые значения не известны, то лучше смотреть в сторону `Dictionary`

Comment: @Monk, ну вообще свои типы можно и в run-time создавать тоже

Comment: @Grundy только толку от таких я не вижу в данном вопросе =)

Comment: @Monk, а это уже совсем другой вопрос :)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вам нужно [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/essfb559.aspx).

Например:

```
enum Direction
{
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West
};

Direction d = (Direction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Direction), "North");
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/Mj3xWE

Comment: я плохо обьянсли, добавил апдейт

Comment: @Demolver: Хм, а что означает «сделать» enum? У вас такого энума в программе _нет_ на момент компиляции, или есть? Это важно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

### Из string:

```
CustomEnum enm = (CustomEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomEnum), str);
```

и еще если интересно можете прочитать дополнительно [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522831/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-int-%D0%B2-enum/522832#522832).