# Конвертация KeyCode в int и обратно

Tags: unity3d

Я решил написать скрипт для сохранения раслкадки клавиатуры в json файл. Нужно мне это для того чтобы игрок мог самостоятельно назначать клавиши для разных действий (прыжок - <kbd>space</kbd>, взаимодествие - <kbd>e</kbd> и тд). В самом файле запись выглядит как-то так:

```
{"actionName":"FORWARD","actionCode":"87"}
```

Конвертацию `KeyCode` я делаю следующим образом:

```
KeyCode code = KeyCode.W;
int intCode = Convert.ToInt32(code);
```

**Вопрос** в том как именно мне преобразовать полученное значение `int` обратно в `KeyCode`? Возможно есть другие способы чтобы сохранить данную информацию в файл, хотел бы это тоже знать. Я пробовал сохранять таким же способом но в строку но при конвертации строка преобратает нижний регистр.

Хотел бы использовать `KeyCode` ведь в unity для отслеживания нажатий принимаються только `KeyCode` или `string`.

```
public static bool GetKey(string name);
public static bool GetKey(KeyCode key);
```

Comment: похоже что KeyCode это enum. Посмотри это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522831/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-int-%D0%B2-enum

Comment: @ValeraKvip вы правы это действительно помогло. Я очень признателен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ответ находиться по этой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522831/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-int-%D0%B2-enum)

Но вкратце код будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
//Создадим int переменную с нужным кодом
int intCode = Convert.ToInt32(KeyCode.W);
//Вернём теперь int как KeyCode
KeyCode code = (KeyCode)intCode;
```

Так как `KeyCode` это `enum` его можно конвертировать и интерпретировать в `int`